# How can we show progress bar for upload with FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, winforms, ftp, progress-bar, ftpwebrequest

I am uploading files to ftp using `FtpWebRequest`. I need to show the status that how much is done.

So far my code is:

```
public void Upload(string filename, string url)
{
    FileInfo fileInf = new FileInfo(filename);
    string uri = "ftp://" + url + "/" + fileInf.Name;
    FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
    //string uri = "ftp://" + Host + "/public_html/testing/blogtest/" + fileInf.Name;

    // Create FtpWebRequest object from the Uri provided
    reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));

    // Provide the WebPermission Credintials
    reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);

    // By default KeepAlive is true, where the control connection is not closed
    // after a command is executed.
    reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
    //reqFTP.UsePassive = true;
    // Specify the command to be executed.
    reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    // Specify the data transfer type.
    reqFTP.UseBinary = true;

    // Notify the server about the size of the uploaded file
    reqFTP.ContentLength = fileInf.Length;

    // The buffer size is set to 2kb
    int buffLength = 2048;
    byte[] buff = new byte[buffLength];
    int contentLen;

    // Opens a file stream (System.IO.FileStream) to read the file to be uploaded
    FileStream fs = fileInf.OpenRead();

    // Stream to which the file to be upload is written
    Stream strm = reqFTP.GetRequestStream();

    // Read from the file stream 2kb at a time
    contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);

    // Till Stream content ends
    while (contentLen != 0)
    {
        // Write Content from the file stream to the FTP Upload Stream
        strm.Write(buff, 0, contentLen);
        contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
    }

    // Close the file stream and the Request Stream
    strm.Close();
    fs.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The easiest is to use `BackgroundWorker` and put your code into `DoWork` event handler. And report progress with `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress`.

The basic idea:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var ftpWebRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://example.com");
    ftpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    using (var inputStream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
    using (var outputStream = ftpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        var buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
        int totalReadBytesCount = 0;
        int readBytesCount;
        while ((readBytesCount = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytesCount);
            totalReadBytesCount += readBytesCount;
            var progress = totalReadBytesCount * 100.0 / inputStream.Length;
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)progress);
        }
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Make sure `WorkerReportsProgress` is enabled

```
backgroundWorker2.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
```

With `BackgroundWorker` you can also easily implement upload cancellation.

Comment: yes but reslution is not soo good uploading 3mb file showed only 23% 53 and then 100

Comment: @Afnan Bashir - you can adjust the buffer size to your needs.

Answer (score 5):

A trivial example of FTP upload using `FtpWebRequest` with WinForms progress bar using [`Task` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Run Upload on background thread
    Task.Run(() => Upload());
}

private void Upload()
{
    string url = "ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip";
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\local\path\file.zip"))
    using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        progressBar1.Invoke(
            (MethodInvoker)delegate { 
                progressBar1.Maximum = (int)fileStream.Length; });

        byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
        int read;
        while ((read = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            progressBar1.Invoke(
                (MethodInvoker)delegate {
                    progressBar1.Value = (int)fileStream.Position; });
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

The core upload code is based on:
[Upload and download a file to/from FTP server in C#/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44606028/850848)

Answer (score 1):

A cancellable approach using the async/await pattern's IProgress interface, taking advantage of [overlapped I/O](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365683(v=vs.85).aspx) if available. Refer to [KB156932](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/156932) to determine if your scenario qualifies. The cancellation token is checked before opening the streams, but otherwise is offloaded to the streams' async methods while the file is being transferred.

I have done very little benchmarking, but suspect this is only practical when sending large files. The performance of using overlapped I/O may degrade with smaller files and especially smaller buffer sizes.

```cpp
public async Task FtpAsync(string sourceFile, Uri destinationUri, string user, SecureString password, IProgress<decimal> progress, CancellationToken token)
{
  const int bufferSize = 128 * 1024;  // 128kb buffer
  progress.Report(0m);

  var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destinationUri);
  request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
  request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password);

  token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

  using (var fileStream = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, bufferSize, true))
  {
    using (var ftpStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
    {
      var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
      int read;

      while ((read = await fileStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, token)) > 0)
      {
        await ftpStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read, token);
        var percent = 100m * ((decimal)fileStream.Position / fileStream.Length);
        progress.Report(percent);
      }
    }
  }

  var response = (FtpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
  var success = (int)response.StatusCode >= 200 && (int)response.StatusCode < 300;
  response.Close();
  if (!success)
    throw new Exception(response.StatusDescription);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), it allows you to run a time consuming task while the GUI still is responsive and also provides progress/cancellation.

Comment: This is a borderline link-only answer. You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.