# c# link progess bar with file upload

Tags: c#, ftp

I have a method I call to upload a file (which was as it should).

```
       private void uploadFile()
    {

        try
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("\n\nStarting file upload");
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftpservername.com/test.htm");
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword");
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

            richTextBox1.AppendText(reader.ReadToEnd());

            richTextBox1.AppendText("\n\nUpload Complete");

            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
            request = null;
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I also have a progress bar (labelled uploadProgress) which I would like to show how much it left to upload.

I have a download section also which does has a working link to a progress bar, the code is from this page

> https://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/how-to-download-a-file-in-c-progressbar-and-download-speed/

but I cannot see how to use

```
    progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
```

`Show the percentage on our label.
    labelPerc.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
 
    // Update the label with how much data have been downloaded so far and the total size of the file we are currently downloading
    labelDownloaded.Text = string.Format("{0} MB's / {1} MB's",
        (e.BytesReceived / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"),
        (e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"));`

into my existing Upload Method.

can someone help me please ?

Comment: This is a duplicate. Use that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6341079/4992212

Comment: Thank you. I did look if the answer already existed, just obviously not hard enough :-)