# In a .NET C # project, ¿ is possible start progressbar when call request.GetRequestStream()?

Tags: c#, ftp, progress-bar

i use this solution [How can we show progress bar for upload with FtpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341024/how-can-we-show-progress-bar-for-upload-with-ftpwebrequest) and work well whit progressbar.

but when at request.GetRequestStream(), i take like 1 or 2 seconds of delay, and seems program is bugged at eyes of client.

Thanks in advance,

Greetings,

EDIT:

i add the followin lines to make GetRequestStream faster.

```
    request.Proxy = null;
    request.ServicePoint.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
    request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
    request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit= 20;
    ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a Backgroundworker for the GetRequestStream()? If not, your Window will be freezed until the request is done.

[BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: No, i am using  " Thread bgThread = new Thread( new ThreadStart(async () =>" but i think should use backgroundworker for make this app. Meanwhile i optimize the connection, edited principal post.